# Looping Through Ranges, Rows, and Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large data dump that I need to sort through with a snippet of the information below.

```
    Part #  A   B   C   Op
    2403253 1   7   4   Foundry
    2403253 2   8   5   Foundry
    2403253 3   9   6   Foundry
    2403253 4   1   7   Foundry
    2403253 5   2   8   Outside
    2403253 6   3   9   Machining
    2403253 7   4   1   Machining
    2403253 8   5   2   Polishing
    2403253 9   6   3   Polishing
    2403254 1   7   4   Foundry
    2403254 2   8   5   Foundry
    2403254 3   9   6   Machining
    2403254 4   1   7   Polishing
    2403256 5   2   8   Foundry
    2403256 6   3   9   Foundry
    2403256 7   4   1   Machining
    2403256 8   5   2   Polishing
    2403257 9   6   3   Foundry
    2403257 1   7   4   Foundry
    2403257 2   8   5   Machining
    2403257 3   9   6   Polishing
    2403258 4   1   7   Foundry
    2403258 5   2   8   Foundry
    2403258 6   3   9   Polishing
```

What I am looking to do is loop through each of the "Part #s" and pair it with each of the "Ops" adding A, B, & C together to get a final result like:

```
    Part #  A   B   C   Op
    2403253 X   X   X   Foundry
            X   X   X   Machining 
            X   X   X   Outside
            X   X   X   Polishing
    2403254 X   X   X   Foundry
            X   X   X   Machining 
            X   X   X   Outside
            X   X   X   Polishing
    2403256 X   X   X   Foundry
            X   X   X   Machining 
            X   X   X   Outside
            X   X   X   Polishing
    2403257 X   X   X   Foundry
            X   X   X   Machining 
            X   X   X   Outside
            X   X   X   Polishing
    2403258 X   X   X   Foundry
            X   X   X   Machining 
            X   X   X   Outside
            X   X   X   Polishing
```

I am not sure how to go about it. Any help is appreciated. I have tried comprehending looping, consolidating, and some others.

Comment: Is there a fixed number of "Op"s, and would it matter if all of those Ops were displayed in the final results even if the values of A, B and C were 0?  (i.e. can the results have a fixed number of lines generated for each Part #, or do you need to have only 3 lines shown if a Part # only has source records for 3 Ops?)

Comment: Every Part will need each of the 4 ops even if it is zero. It may also be easier to have 4 of the same Part #s as well which can be used later with excel's Filter.

Comment: And is the data currently sorted, or can it be sorted, into Ops within Part# order?  The process is so much simpler if it is.

Comment: Data comes sorted by part number, numerically. The Ops within each part number is not sorted as shown and comes in every which order.

Answer (score 0):

I was bored while eating my breakfast, so here is some (untested) code:

```
Option Explicit

Private rowDst As Long
Private Results() As Integer
Private currentPartNo As String
Private Ops(4) As String
Private wsDst As Worksheet
Private op As Integer
Private abc As Integer

Sub RunMe()
    'Switch off ScreenUpdating to speed up execution time
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim rowSrc As Long
    Ops(1) = "Foundry"
    Ops(2) = "Machining"
    Ops(3) = "Outside"
    Ops(4) = "Polishing"

    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDst = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    currentPartNo = ""

    rowSrc = 2
    rowDst = 2
    Do While wsSrc.Cells(rowSrc, 1).Value <> ""
        If wsSrc.Cells(rowSrc, 1).Value <> currentPartNo Then
            'Different part #, so need to write out results for previous part #
            WriteResults
            'Keep track of current part # so we know when to write out results
            currentPartNo = wsSrc.Cells(rowSrc, 1).Value
            'Clear out current values from Results array
            ReDim Results(3, 4) As Integer
        End If
        'Determine Op position
        For op = 1 To 4
            If wsSrc.Cells(rowSrc, 5).Value = Ops(op) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'Loop through A, B and C, adding values into Results array
        For abc = 1 To 3
            Results(abc, op) = Results(abc, op) + wsSrc.Cells(rowSrc, abc + 1).Value
        Next
        'Increment row pointer
        rowSrc = rowSrc + 1
    Loop
    'Write results for final part #
    WriteResults

    'Switch ScreenUpdating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub WriteResults()
    If currentPartNo <> "" Then
        wsDst.Cells(rowDst + 0, 1).Value = currentPartNo
        For op = 1 To 4
            wsDst.Cells(rowDst + op - 1, 5).Value = Ops(op)
            For abc = 1 To 3
                wsDst.Cells(rowDst + op - 1, abc + 1).Value = Results(abc, op)
            Next
        Next
        rowDst = rowDst + 4
        currentPartNo = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

(I really shouldn't be providing code for you - StackOverflow is here to help you resolve the problems you have with **your** code but, as I said, I was bored.)

Answer (score 0):

As per the below code the results will be put into G,H,I,J,K columns

```
Dim records As Integer, count As Integer, x As String
records = 24
count = 1
Dim ops(4) As Variant
ops(1) = "Foundry"
ops(2) = "Machining"
ops(3) = "Outside"
ops(4) = "Polishing"

For i = 2 To records + 1
    If x <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then
        x = Cells(i, 1).Value
        For op = 1 To 4
            For j = 2 To records + 1
                If Cells(j, 1).Value = x And Cells(j, 5).Value = ops(op) Then
                    a = a + Cells(j, 2).Value
                    b = b + Cells(j, 3).Value
                    c = c + Cells(j, 4).Value
                End If
            Next j

            If op = 1 Then
                Cells(count, 7).Value = x
            End If
            Cells(count, 8).Value = a
            Cells(count, 9).Value = b
            Cells(count, 10).Value = c
            Cells(count, 11).Value = ops(op)

            count = count + 1
            a = 0
            b = 0
            c = 0
        Next op

    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the precise format you show above, a Pivot table can give you similar information in a slightly different layout.

Using your data, drag `Part #` and `Op` to the Rows area; Drag `A`, `B` and `C` to the Values area for the Sum

[image]

The result:

[image]

Or, if you select Outline form:

[image]